# Windows 1.0 menu

Tags: windows, colors

Could anyone tell me what was the last menu point under Control Panel/ Preferences/ Screen Colors in Windows 1.0?

It should be right under the following: Title Bar Text, Window Frame, Menu Bar, Menu Text, (???).

[image: see image here]

Comment: He posted this from the windows 1.0 era too. It's the lag that made it 25 years late.

Comment: He has it running in a VM while in a time machine, explains it all.

Comment: In case anyone really wants to answer this...http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r1Uk1oJIzo

Comment: [Install it](http://ompldr.org/vOGRmdw/windows-1.03-kit.zip) and check?

Answer (score 4):

It's "`Screen Background`".

[image: screenshot]

(This was also guessable by the "Hue" position.)

Comment: Did you install it? ( just curious from your comment above)

Comment: I did. (See also: my profile text)